# How can I compare range of values in case statement in java?

Tags: java

I want to use same case statement when `i` is less than 5. But it's not working. Giving me an error that `incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int`

```
class temp{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int i=1;
    switch(i){
       case i < 5 :
       System.out.println("Works");
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me solving this.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: That's not how `switch` works. Use `if` instead.

Comment: Loads of examples on the web - too generic question

Answer (score 1):

You can't use boolean values for `case`. The statement `i < 5` returns either `True` or `False`. You should use `if` instead.

```
class temp{
  public static void main(String args){
    int i=1;
    if (i < 5)
       System.out.println("Works");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case i < 5  It produce boolean result. which is not compatible with integer
```

If you want to compare multiple conditions then use switch case.

```
switch(i){

  case 1 :
  case 2 :
  case 3 :
  case 4 : System.out.println("Works");
  break;

}
```

In you code you are handling only one condition so, use `if` condition instead of `switch`.

```
public static void main(String args){
    int i=1;

    if(i < 5)
    System.out.println("Works");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use conditional statements in `case`,they can have constants only

you can write like this

```
case 5:
```

or

```
case 6:
```

in particular,hence `case <5` is something not acceptable here according to the syntax

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a `switch-case` block, which is used as a lookup table to *specific* values. You want an `if-then-else` block:

```
if(i<5)
{
  \\do stuff
}
else if(\* Some other condition *\)
{
 \\ do other stuff
}
else
{
 \\ default case
}
```